# How to set APIs middlewares for public pages with laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, rest, api

I'm currently working on a SPA with Laravel rest APIs and react frontend. Most of the application works with `Auth:Api` middleware and passport driver, but I need some of the API routes to be consumed by public pages, without login.

I want to make this API routes consumable by the client but not accessible by the web browser (i.e. going directly to www.site.com/api URL). Searching on the web I haven't found many posts on this issue, can someone give me hints?

Comment: Hello Gen; to understand clearly; Do you want your back-end routes to be accessible by front end but not any other places ? If i  open google chrome developer console, and on network tab if capture request, i can replay it. You don't want that ?

Comment: @Ersoy Yes. I want to make as hard as possible to access the raw (json) data of this public pages. I don't want to expose the apis to the average user. I want all the requests to be refused if not coming from my frontend.
I thought of doing that by taking advance of passport tokens. Can you put me on the right rail?